# Signed apk can not install in older OS version

Tags: android

now I use Android Oreo 8.0.1 All Can In Install Well. But not with my friends Smartphone who uses android Marshmellow And Lolipop. i did not try nougat
This my repo :https://github.com/ElclarkKuhu/EDchat
Btw the Targetsdk 27 and minimum 15

Comment: Please clarify your question - what do you want to achieve, what is not working? Is there any error message?

Comment: Please use `adb logcat -v time` to collect log while installing your app on "Marshmellow And Lolipop devices" and post the log.

Comment: You obviously need to specify a lower `minSDKVersion` in your Manifest. And use the **support library** in your app.

Comment: Its Say "App Not Installed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

İf you want to use RecylerView in older apis , use in your build.gradle this piece of code:
     implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

Comment: i get error with 26.1.0 And Press Alt+Enter It Updated to 27.0.2 its will work?

Comment: Yes i thing.Just implement this.